# Symfony2 turn autoescaping off in php template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

There is way to turn autoescaping off in twig template in Symfony2. Like so:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{ child.vars.label }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

How can I do something like this in PHP template? I got expanded choice type in my form, and I need to use images as labels. But Symfony keeps escaping my img tags.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**
Sorry for misunderstood, but php templates have no autoescaping. If you want escaping in php templates you must do:

```
<?php echo $view->escape($var) ?>
```

---

**Original answer:**
In Twig use raw filter - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

```
{{ child.vars.label | raw }}
```

Comment: The question is about PHP templates, not Twig.

Comment: There is no autoescaping in php templates.